# Changing class not working

Tags: jquery

Total Jquery noob, working my way along.  It's hosted here: [mySite](http://bungle.ca/jquery/)

Of interest is the footer.  Would like to press site map and have footer expand nicely to show a nice site map which it's doing.  Would like to change the site map button to another button to close it up.

Using replaceWith() it changes the button just fine but I cannot use the new HTML to do anything, it is totally unresponsive.  Have been struggling with it for an hour and a half, trying things like toggleClass() etc.  Cannot get it to work.  Not concerned about anything else I may have screwed up in the closing methods, prefer to learn it myself.

Cheers.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".siteMap").click(function(){
   $("#footer").animate({
      height:  '150px'
      }, 1000);
    $("#table").fadeIn('20000');
    $(".siteMap").replaceWith('<span class="close"><a>CLOSE</a></span>')
   }); // end .click

  $(".close").click(function(){
    $("#footer").css('height', '25px');
    $("#table").fadeOut('20000');
    $(".close").replaceWith('<span class="siteMap"><a>SITE MAP</a></span>');
   }); // end .click
  }); // end .ready
</script>

<div id="footer">
 <div id="table">
  <table width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
   </tr>                    
   <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
   </tr>    
   <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link One</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 <span id="home"><a href="#">HOME</a></span>
 <span id="top"><a href="#banner">TOP</a></span>
 <span class="siteMap"><a>SITE MAP</a></span>
</div>

#table{
    display:    none;
    z-index:    999;
    }

#table  table{
    border: 0;
    }

#table  td{
    border: 0;
    }

#footer{
    padding:    5px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid   #ff0000;
    border-radius:  20px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('../images/backgroundNavy.jpg') top left;
    background-repeat:  repeat-x;
    }

#footer a{
    text-decoration:    none;
    color:  white;
    font-size:  15px;
    font-family:    proxima;
    font-weight:    bold;
    }
```

Comment: try .removeClass and .addClass, I think there is no such thing as replace class. But your solution is a nice work around.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what your question is. BTW, it's usually better to hide/show elements rather than constantly change the HTML.

Comment: Cheers,  I am trying to get "Site Map" to expand the footer to show a nice table full of links, and in doing so change to a button that says "close" and will close the footer to it's original state.  It opens just fine, and the table changes from display:none to displayed.  It just will not close.

Comment: Thanks all, got it.  Don't know how to pick best, they're all great answers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is becoming unresponsive is because you do not re-bind the click event to the element.

After calling replaceWith you must then re-bind the click to that element.

However I'd recommend showing/hiding your site map/close buttons instead of creating them new. With this approach you will not need to rebind the click.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The elements you are attaching the click events to does not exist at the time you are binding the events. You'll need to delegate those events to an element that does exist, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#footer").on('click', ".siteMap", function() {
        $("#footer").animate({
            height: '150px'
        }, 1000);
        $("#table").fadeIn('20000');
        $(".siteMap").replaceWith('<span class="close"><a>CLOSE</a></span>')
    }); // end .click
    $("#footer").on('click', ".close", function() {
        $("#footer").css('height', '25px');
        $("#table").fadeOut('20000');
        $(".close").replaceWith('<span class="siteMap"><a>SITE MAP</a></span>');
    }); // end .click
}); // end .ready​​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/444/)

`on()` only works in jQuery 1.7+, for older versions there is `delegate()` or `live()`.

The best thing would be to just hide/show the elements, and not constantly replace them, like so : [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/447/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is having is that you are attaching the click event handlers to elements when the page loads.  However, when the page first loads your `<span>` with class "close" isn't part of the DOM yet, because you are dynamically adding it later.  When you add it later it doesn't have the event handler attached to it.

One way to get around this would be to use the JQuery `.on()` method, which will attach event handlers to all existing elements that match you selector, as well as any future elements that are added.  [Here are the JQuery docs for that.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Your JavaScript would look like this (note you need to make the same change when adding the event handler to your "siteMap" element, or you won't be able to show the siteMap a second time after it has been collapsed.)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#footer").on("click", ".siteMap", function(){
   $("#footer").animate({
      height:  '150px'
      }, 1000);
    $("#table").fadeIn('20000');
    $(".siteMap").replaceWith('<span class="close"><a>CLOSE</a></span>')
   }); // end .click

  $("#footer").on("click", ".close", function(){
    $("#footer").css('height', '25px');
    $("#table").fadeOut('20000');
    $(".close").replaceWith('<span class="siteMap"><a>SITE MAP</a></span>');
   }); // end .click
  }); // end .ready​​​​
```

However I agree with @Ariel's comment that changing the HTML in situations like this isn't usually the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your javascript is parsed BEFORE you ever create an element with class `.close`.  To solve this, jquery has a built in [on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('.close').on('click',function(){
    //your function here
});
```